# Sending arguments from PHP to Perl on Linux

Tags: php, perl, encoding, shell-exec

I'm trying to run a Perl script on a remote (currently virtual) Linux server using `shell_exec()`. The Perl file requires 3 arguments, a file name, an encoding and the contents of the file.

It's made, to write specific lines into Perl files made by other people.

The script should open the file with the file name in `arg[0]` with the encoding in `arg[1]` and write in it the contents in `arg[2]`.

I managed to get it to work, as in it writes the contents to the files, but since this program writes over files where the encoding is important, I would have to write them over in just the same encoding they were in originally, and since we use accented characters I need to make sure that those work properly as well. How could I do that?

I will add code if needed.

EDIT: Code:

Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
#use strict;

my $fileName = "";
my $contents = "";
my $encoding = "";

if(@ARGV != 3){
    print "use: documentor_write_file fileName encoding contents";
    exit;
}else{

    $fileName = $ARGV[0];
    $encoding = $ARGV[1];
    $contents = $ARGV[2];

}

sub write_file{

    open(DATA,"> :encoding($encoding)",$fileName);
    $contents =~ s/&amp;/&/g;

    $contents =~ s/&dollar;/$/g;

    $contents =~ s/&lt;/</g;

    $contents =~ s/&gt;/>/g;

    $contents =~ s/\\&quot;/\"/g;

    $contents =~ s/&cent;/¢/g;
    $contents =~ s/&pound;/£/g;
    $contents =~ s/&yen;/¥/g;
    $contents =~ s/&euro;/€/g;
    $contents =~ s/&copy;/©/g;
    $contents =~ s/&reg;/®/g;

    print(DATA);

    print DATA $contents;

}

write_file;

close(DATA);
exit;
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['stf'])){
    $ret = "";

    $fn = $_POST['fn'];     //File name
    $enc = $_POST['enc'];       //Encoding
    $cont = $_POST['content'];  //Content

    $cont = str_replace("\"","\\\"", $cont);    //Replaces " with \"
    $cont = pg_escape_string($cont);        //
    $cont = htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($cont));  //
    $cont = str_replace("$", "&dollar;", $cont);    //replaces $ with &dollar;

    $cmd2 = "perl /documentor_write_file.pl $fn $enc " . "\"" . $cont . "\"";
    $ret = shell_exec($cmd2);
    //print($ret . " - " . $cmd2);
}
```

---

Example:

File contents: (Perl file)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

BEGIN{push @INC,"/usr/local/dpdregister/processes/common/";}
eval {require 'dpdregister.conf'; use vars qw ( $dbh ) };

=history
<HIST>
history2 áéűáé
több history
</HIST>
=cut
```

What it actually writes into the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

BEGIN{push @INC,\&amp;quot;/usr/local/dpdregister/processes/common/\&amp;quot;;}
eval {require ''dpdregister.conf''; use vars qw ( &dollar;dbh ) };

=history
&amp;lt;HIST&amp;gt;
history2 &amp;aacute;&amp;eacute;\x{00c5}\x{00b1}&amp;aacute;&amp;eacute;
t&amp;ouml;bb history

&amp;lt;/HIST&amp;gt;
=cut
```

Comment: Its better to add code, people can easily understand what you are trying to  achieve.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. I'll just figure out which code I need to add

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to write everything as UTF-8?

It would need a one-time conversion of all these Perl files to UTF-8 (which can also be done in Perl, if needed; just don't forget to set the `use utf8;` pragma), but after that you would only need to check that what you are sending to the file is actually UTF-8.

Comment: Sadly, I'm working with the files of a multinational company, we have code here that is old enough that we don't dare touch it since a lot may depend on them working correctly. This is a side-project, that would work with collecting data from these scripts and write information into them as comments, but i cannot change anything about the working of these scripts or any comments that are already in there.